# Python and html inputs

Tags: python, html

I was working on making a sort of personal assistant local website. I wanted to type in an input and it go to a python file which would do an action based on the input. It would either open a webpage or show extra information on the same page, or something of the sort, without reloading the page. How would I go about doing that?

An example:

```
Open website:
-> Type in "facebook.com"
    -> Python script output= opens facebook in new tab
-> Type in "Open schedule"
    -> Python script output= Produces a summary followed by a detailed account 
                             of my schedule on the same page
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the browser?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Going to a URL is just one example. In a browser I can do that but I cannot do the second example. If I type "Open Schedule", I want it to give me a summary of my agenda. If I type "Add TASK to LIST" I want it to do that. But that is python stuff. My question is how can I take an input from an HTML input field and make python act on it by changing the webpage without reloading.

Comment: Actually, you can do those things without python, if you wanted to.  You can store browser data via JavaScript in things like localStorage and cookies, and so the data wouldn't be lost if you tried to open a new page.  However, if there is some data on the computer/server side that you do not want the browser to access, flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a python microframework for WebApps that allows you to interact with webpages from python files.  I'm sure there are dozens of other similar libraries out there, but I've worked with flask personally. Either of these options are viable.

Comment: I don't know how to actually make Python go to a webpage or show your schedule though I imagine there is probably already libraries out there that can complete that task for you.  What I see as the real problem here is having your website decide what to do with a given input.  I think the best way to go about that is to use something like keywords.  So "Open" runs the schedule script; maybe "Go to" or recognizing the ".com" runs a browser; perhaps "Weather" triggers a weather widget.

Comment: @Guest01 Right, that is what I want. I know the python and the html individually,  but I don't know how to make them cooperate with each other.

Comment: @ajc2000 thats probably the solution thanks!! 
EDIT: you can post that as an answer so I can select it if u want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to have a web application in which python code redirects, controls, and obtains data concerning HTML pages, then Flask, a python microframework, is a great option.

Here is a link to the main Flask page, which should have instructions for documentation and installation:

[http://flask.pocoo.org/](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Additionally, here are some great tutorial series that really helped me get started with Flask:

[The Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

[YouTube Playlist with detailed, step-by-step tutorials about many of Flask's features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mr90d7fp3SE&feature=youtu.be&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcOS4l8RCWh0olq_je0OKaP)